# Place text with background over image like Snapchat

Tags: ios, objective-c

How can I implement a text feature like Snapchat where a user types in a string of text with a background so the text is visible, and can position it on the screen vertically?

This is what Snapchat's text bar looks like.

[image: bearhug]

Comment: What did you try , posting your code would be helpful .

Comment: I haven't tried anything, I don't really know where to start other than making a editable text view.